# RasPi / Win10 PHP filenames (cifs) charset

Tags: php, windows, apache, character-encoding, raspberry-pi

all!

I can't figure it out and am very confused about charset handling right now. The following configuration:

a) Windows 10 with Apache, PHP and MySQL - external USB HDD published as 'video1' with video files containing meta info about content in filename - containing special chars (i.e. german umlauts), too.

A PHP script reads (scandir) all filenames recursively and displays (utf8_encode) the extracted meta info via html. This script works like a charm since a few years now.

b) RasPi 2 with Apache, PHP and MySQL - same HDD mounted (cifs) at /mnt/video1.

Same script executes but displays odd characters. If I remove the utf8_encode the display is weird at the Win10 side, but correct at the RasPi side. What do I have to do so that the script works on **both** servers?

An example script: (change only $directory = ... for Windows and RasPi side)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>

  <HEAD>
    <?php include("metatags.txt"); ?>
    <TITLE>Charset Test</TITLE>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>

<?php
  function scan_dir_recursive( $dir, $result ) {
    //echo "Entering: " . $dir . "<BR>";
    $direntries = scandir( $dir );
    //echo "Entries: "; var_dump( $direntries ); echo "<BR>";
    foreach ( $direntries as $entry ) {
      if ( is_dir( $dir . $entry )) {
        if (( $entry <> "." ) and ( $entry <> ".." )) {
          $result = scan_dir_recursive( $dir . $entry . "/", $result );
        }
      }
      if ( is_file( $dir . $entry )) {
        //echo( "<B> + " . $dir . $entry . "</B><BR>" );
        $result[] = $dir . $entry;
      }
    }
    //echo "Result: "; var_dump( $result ); echo "<BR>";
    return $result;
  }

  function displayheader( $mode ) {
    switch ( $mode ) {
      case 1:
        echo( "unverändert" );
        break;
      case 2:
        echo( "utf8_encode" );
        break;
      }
  }

  function displayentry( $entry, $mode ) {
    switch ( $mode ) {
      case 1:
        $result = $entry;
        break;
      case 2:
        $result = utf8_encode( $entry );
        break;
    }
    echo $result;
  }

  $directory = "//192.168.1.20/video1/charset/";
  //$directory = "/mnt/video1/charset/";
  $videolist = array();
  $videolist = scan_dir_recursive( $directory, $videolist );
?>

<?php
  for ( $t = 1; $t <= 2; $t++ ) {
?>
    <TABLE>
      <TR>
        <TH><?php displayheader( $t );?></TH>
      </TR>
<?php
  foreach ( $videolist as $entry ) {
?>
      <TR>
        <TD><?php displayentry( $entry, $t );?></TD>
      </TR>
<?php
  }
?>
    </TABLE>
<?php
  }
?>

  </BODY>

</HTML>
```

The script displays the list correct with utf8_encode but displays black carets with "?" without. The RasPi on the other hand displays the list correct without the encoding, but 2-byte garbage (an 'A' with ~ above plus a 2nd char) using the encoding. An "ls -la" at the CLI of the RasPi displays the filenames correct, too, as does a "dir" on the Windows PC.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Michael

Comment: If both systems read the files from the same file system, then the cause of the issue is the encoding of file names in that file system which apparently is not in unicode. Most likely you are dealing with the old fashioned "windows codepage bla bla encoding", basically a 8 bit encoding (ISO) which got broken a bit my Microsoft to make it incompatible. Take a look at the mount options for mounting the file system on the Raspberry Pi. You should be able fix the mapping but for that you first need to find out what encoding the file system actually uses.

Comment: The DOS-Box (cmd) at the Windows side displays the filenames correct. The CLI at the RasPi side displays the filenames correct, too. I don't use any iocharset=... options when mounting via cifs. Clarification: The HDD is not (never) cnnected directly to the RasPi. Even the RasPi PHP displays the filenames correct. The problems arise only because I have to use the utf8_encode at the Windows PHP side. So it might be a PHP config issue there, but I have no clue. If it _is_ I would then (and only then) edit all scripts at the Windows side.

Comment: You dig in the dark, that makes no sense. Go and find out exactly what the actual encoding is instead of trying around and doing guess work. So dump things into a file and use a HexEditor to take a close look.

Comment: What things would you like me to dump? You did realize that the problem is with the file _names_ and not with the file _contents_, didn't you? A "dir /s > dir.txt" won't help with it, I'd guess. As I mentioned: The filenames are displayed correct in a DOS box. All I can say right now is that it is a 2 TB NTFS USB3 HDD factory formatted, I just plugged it in. Please name me a way or tool to get more info.